# Tkcalendar clear DateEntry after moving focus

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have a DateEntry widget and a button to clear the DateEntry contents. I want the DateEntry to be blank unless the user selects a date.

My problem is if I select the DateEntry widget and give it focus, then using the clear button doesn't work the first time because the DateEntry is auto-completing after losing focus.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

def clearDateEntry():
    clearButton.focus_set()
    myDateEntry.delete(0,END)

root=Tk()

myDateEntry=DateEntry(root)
myDateEntry.pack()
myDateEntry.delete(0,END)

clearButton=Button(root,text='clear',command=clearDateEntry)
clearButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

To replicate: give DateEntry focus, then click clear.

In the `clearDateEntry()` function, I move the focus to the clear button first which I'd expect would trigger the auto-complete so that I can delete it straight after, but that doesn't work.

How do I make `clearDateEntry()` actually clear the DateEntry on the first go? If there's a way to turn off DateEntry's auto-complete, that would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DateEntry` is set to validate the entry content on focus out (the `validate` option is set to 'focusout') and if the content is not a valid date, today's date is put in the entry. The idea being to always have a valid date inside the entry.

You can therefore simply get rid of this behavior by setting

`myDateEntry.configure(validate='none')`

This way the entry content is no longer validated on focus out, however it will still be validated when clicking on the drop-down button so there shouldn't be issue with invalid dates when displaying the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to delay your `delete` method by 1 ms:

```
def clearDateEntry():
    clearButton.focus_set()
    root.after(1, myDateEntry.delete, 0,END)
```